# php stdClass object Nested object for child values

Tags: php, laravel, object, stdclass

I am working on stdClass Object in laravel. I have to combine values from two table. i.e. first one containing some questions and other one is containing their multiple choice answers. How to combine the result in a way that the questions object could contain its answer object as nested object. I want the structure like that:

```
stdClass Object
(
[question_id] => 4
[title] => How to add data?
[options] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 1
[question_id] => 4
[option_title] => By any device
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 2
[question_id] => 4
[option_title] => By mobile
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 3
[question_id] => 4
[option_title] => By Laptop
)
)
stdClass Object
(
[question_id] => 5
[title] => Where to add data?
[options] => Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 1
[question_id] => 5
[option_title] => Lahore
)

[1] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 2
[question_id] => 5
[option_title] => Karachi
)

[2] => stdClass Object
(
[id] => 3
[question_id] => 5
[option_title] => Multan
)

);
```

Comment: Again, you must share with us what you have tried yourself. Posting question like this will not help you in getting your problem solved. However, Just by reading your problem statement, I think you should use joins to connect your two tables and then use group by on question_id to group the results.

Comment: I did following but getting wrong result as question is no more as object:
    $result = [];foreach($question_data as $q) {
    $result[$q['title']][] = [
    'id' => $q['id'],
    'question_id' => $q['question_id'],
    'option_q_id' => $q['option_q_id'],
    'option_title' => $q['option_title']
    ];
    }

Answer (score 0):

It was little edgy using foreach with keys. Finally developed following code and it worked perfectly:

```
foreach ($question_data as $key => $question) {
            foreach ($option_data as $key2 => $opt) {
                if ($question_data[$key]->question_id == $option_data[$key2]['question_id'] && $question->q_type != 3) {
                    $question->options[] = [
                        'question_id' => $option_data[$key2]['question_id'],
                        'option_id' => $option_data[$key2]['id'],
                        'option_title' => $option_data[$key2]['option_title']
                    ];
                } else if($question->q_type == 3) {
                    $question->options = [];
                }
            }
        }
```

And it provided following result:

```
"question_data": [
        {
            "question_id": 2,
            "title": "Describe about visit",
            "q_type": 3,
            "question_group_id": 1,
            "options": []
        },
        {
            "question_id": 3,
            "title": "How to upload data",
            "q_type": 2,
            "question_group_id": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "question_id": 3,
                    "option_id": 4,
                    "option_title": "By any device"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 3,
                    "option_id": 5,
                    "option_title": "By mobile"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 3,
                    "option_id": 6,
                    "option_title": "By camera"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 3,
                    "option_id": 7,
                    "option_title": "By Laptop"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 3,
                    "option_id": 8,
                    "option_title": "No answer"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "question_id": 4,
            "title": "How to add question?",
            "q_type": 3,
            "question_group_id": 1,
            "options": []
        },
        {
            "question_id": 5,
            "title": "Multi selection is working?",
            "q_type": 1,
            "question_group_id": 1,
            "options": [
                {
                    "question_id": 5,
                    "option_id": 9,
                    "option_title": "Yes"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 5,
                    "option_id": 10,
                    "option_title": "No"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 5,
                    "option_id": 11,
                    "option_title": "Not Confirmed"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 5,
                    "option_id": 12,
                    "option_title": "In progress"
                },
                {
                    "question_id": 5,
                    "option_id": 13,
                    "option_title": "Testing"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```